# PHP7 gives error "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64 /php/modules/mysqli.so'

Tags: php, mysqli, php-7

On a new server I installed PHP 7.0.10 and mysql.
When I try to connect to the database via a php file using mysqli_connect() it gives the error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /opt/http/blabla/src/class_db.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /opt/http/blabla/src/main.php(17): _Db->connect() #1 {main} thrown in /opt/http/blabla/src/class_db.php on line 19

**This is caused because PHP cannot load the mysql shared object:**

> [root@nl2 httpd]# php -v
>   PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64
>   /php/modules/mysqli.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so: symbol 
>   mysql_change_user, version libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file 
>   libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time reference in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 7.0.11 (cli) (built: Sep 17 2016 09:23:18) ( NTS )

Both libraries exist:

```
[root@nl2 httpd]# ls -l /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 141856 Sep 17 11:39 /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 141856 Sep 17 11:39 /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqli.so
```

Some configuration information:

```
# yum list installed
php70w.x86_64                         7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-cli.x86_64                     7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-common.x86_64                  7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-devel.x86_64                   7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-gd.x86_64                      7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-mysql.x86_64                   7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-opcache.x86_64                 7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-pdo.x86_64                     7.0.10-1.w7
php70w-process.x86_64                 7.0.10-1.w7
mysql55w.x86_64                       5.5.50-1.w
mysql55w-devel.x86_64                 5.5.50-1.w
mysql55w-libs.x86_64                  5.5.50-1.w
mysql55w-server.x86_64                5.5.50-1.w

# cat /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini
;Enable mysqli extension module
extension=mysqli.so
extension=php_mysqli.so
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: That's strange. It should be in the mysql package. Are you sure it's enabled in `php.ini` etc.? Have you restarted the process?

Comment: Stange indeed. In /etc/php.ini there is a [MySQLi] section; that all looks fine.
Also restarted httpd and mysqld. No effect.

Comment: Hmm. Did you check in `phpinfo()` that it's using the PHP ini file you think it is?

Comment: phpinfo() confirms that it uses /etc/php.ini

Answer (score 2):

I would comment, but I don't have enough points. Have you tried:

```
yum -y install php70w-mbstring php70w-mcrypt
```

And then connecting using:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('ip', 'user', 'pass', 'db', port);
```

I think it's an issue of not enough PHP installed!

Comment: How does someone not have enough PHP installed exactly :D?

Comment: :DDD Well, after installing `php7.0` and `php7.0-mysql`, it does seem you do need to also install `php7.0-mcrypt` and `php7.0-mbstring` for certain things to work... then there are the cases when `php7.0-dev` is required, and certainly `php7.0-gd`... My point is that each of these (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.0) are required to be evaluated as to whether or not you currently or would ever need that mod!